# location of moved piece

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a checker variation game.
I am new  to jquery but through some help the pieces can now move around the board.

Is there a way to indicate the start location and end location of a move?

I would also like to disable all piece movement once a move has been made.

current code:

```
$('img').draggable();
$('#tbl td').droppable({
hoverClass: 'over',
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var cell = ui.draggable.appendTo($(this)).css({
        'left': '0',
        'top': '0'
    });
    var row = cell.closest('tr').prevAll().length + 1;
    var col = cell.closest('td').prevAll().length + 1;
    $('#coords').html('Row ' + row + ', Col ' + col);
  }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/bLb3H/

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img').draggable({
    start: function(e, ui) {
        alert('Starting move from position (' + ui.position.top + ', ' + ui.position.left + ')');
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        alert('Ending move at position (' + ui.position.top + ', ' + ui.position.left + ')');
    }
});
$('#tbl td').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'over',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var cell = ui.draggable.appendTo($(this)).css({
            'left': '0',
            'top': '0'
        });
        var row = cell.closest('tr').prevAll().length + 1;
        var col = cell.closest('td').prevAll().length + 1;
        $('#coords').html('Row ' + row + ', Col ' + col);
        $('img').draggable('disable');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. When I run it though the position is always says 0,0. Is there a way that to get the row, col position of the start move?

Comment: On the `draggable` element, try using the `drag` event instead of `start` or `stop`.

Comment: Here's the whole script with starting and ending positions: http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/bLb3H/17/

Comment: It's common practice to click the 'up arrow' or "upvote" an answer that has helped you out. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will definitely click the 'up arrow'.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.
Here is the code:

```
$('img').draggable({
start: function(e, ui) {          
var myCol = $(this).closest("td").index() + 1;
var myRow = $(this).closest("tr").index() + 1;
$('#coords').html('Row ' + myRow + ', Col ' + myCol);            
},
});
$('#tbl td').droppable({
hoverClass: 'over',
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var cell = ui.draggable.appendTo($(this)).css({
        'left': '0',
        'top': '0'
    });
    var row = cell.closest('tr').prevAll().length + 1;
    var col = cell.closest('td').prevAll().length + 1;
    $('#coords').html('Row ' + row + ', Col ' + col);
    $('img').draggable('disable');
}
});
```

and the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/5/

I am not sure though how to replace the current image with the new one that was dragged onto it (currently both images occupy the same cell). Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "current image" and "one dragged onto it". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean when two pieces land on the same space?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try again: I do not want two pieces to occupy the same space. The newest piece dropped should replace the current piece in the same space.

Comment: In that case, you should uniquely identify the pieces with different element names. Here's a good place to start and you can take it from there....  http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/bLb3H/31/

Comment: I am not sure though how to continue after I rename each image.

Comment: I tried removing the image first then appended the new one. This method seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/34/